# how to form array object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below I have a page design, where I have two input boxes.

Name and age.

I also have an add button.

Upon clicking the add button I have span elements with name and age
[image]

and above will be grouped, say "friends"

like wise another group, contains a list of person objects

now i have to store data like

```
group 1- 
   list of objects 
   name - age
   name - age
group 2 -
   list of objects
   name - age
   name - age.
```

later will submit the data.
I have tried `var person = new Object();` , but I am looking to have key value like

```
name: firsname , age: 23
```

or is there any alternative way to achieve this..thanks in advance.

EDIT- i need to do this dynamically upon click add button

Comment: `var person = {name: firstname, age: 23};` then `arrayofpersons.push(person)` ???

Comment: Can you show some code that you have tried? I am confused what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ary = [];
var person = {};
person.name = "nimma";
person.age = 33;
ary.push(person);
person.name = "maddy";
person.age = 30;
ary.push(person);
```

you can also do like this:

```
var ary = [{"name":"nimma","age":33},{"name":"maddy","age":30}];
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/EmCnr/2/)

Comment: i tried, i need to persist the previous data, but this is not working, when i try to add next person object. it overrides

Comment: but it is stored in `ary`. you can also do it like `ary = [{"name":"nimma","age":33},{"name":"maddy","age":30}];`

Comment: it is working now,, i didnt declare var 'ary' as global var, after declaring global it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need jQuery - you can just do:

```
var person = {
    name: firstname,
    age: 23
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var person = [];
```

later on when you need to insert data into the array, do this

```
person.push(
         {
            'name':firsname ,
            'age':23
         }
);
```

Hope that helps!